# date time format adds one more hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetimepicker, momentjs

I am loading from a database table a datetime column - and the value is **2015-03-04 21:00:00 UTC**.

When I try to convert this format into `datetime picker`, like this:

```
date = moment($("#event_start").val()); // date time value from database
$("#event_start").val(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')); // formatting the date time
$("#event_start").datetimepicker(); // "run" it as datetimepicker
```

But instead of the desire output in the `datetimepicker` field `2015-03-04 21:00`, there's **2015-03-04 22:00**.

Why it adds one more hour? How to get rid of it and display the proper time?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you currently located in Western Europe in a country that's on Summer Time? (edit) Or in Central Europe? I suspect that Moment is interpreting that "UTC" correctly, and that you're currently one hour ahead of UTC.

Comment: I am in Germany - so yes, I am. But is there any way to "ignore" it? Because when I create an event, I set its start, save it to database and everything is as it should be.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd do it with Moment. The native JavaScript Date object has APIs for getting parts of the date as UTC values instead of local values, but I don't know how you'd tell Momemt's `.format()` to format the date as if it were UTC.

Comment: What is the *exact* string value of `$("#event_start").val()`?  And what do you mean by "proper time".  Do you want the result to be in UTC or in the local time zone?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/)?

```
$("#event_start").val(date.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/zelubelayi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: `.utc()` would *convert* the moment to UTC, after it's already been interpreted as local time.  That's probably not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I disagree, it sounds like that's is exactly what the OP is looking for...and I quote from his comment above:"I don't know how you'd tell Momemt's .format() to format the date as if it were UTC."

Comment: It depends highly on his response to the question I posed in the OP comments.  If the string end in `Z` or `UTC` or `+00:00`, then your code will work.  If not, he should probably parse it using `moment.utc(thestring)` instead of `moment(thestring).utc()`.

Comment: The string does end in `UTC`.  Again, from the OPs original post: "the value is **2015-03-04 21:00:00 UTC**".

Comment: He says that's the value in the db.  I'm not sure that is the exact string representation being sent to moment.

Comment: I guess It is possible that he's modifying the value before sending it to the client. Valid concerns.